Is Tosefta Avodah Zarah misinterpreting the Talmud with regard to prohibited sexual relations for gentiles?

It is taught in a baraita in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yoḥanan: Any forbidden sexual relations for which a Jewish court administers capital punishment are prohibited to a descendant of Noah, and any forbidden sexual relations for which a Jewish court does not administer capital punishment are not prohibited to a descendant of Noah; this is the statement of Rabbi Meir. And the Rabbis say: There are many types of forbidden sexual relations for which a Jewish court does not administer capital punishment and are nevertheless prohibited to a descendant of Noah (Sanhedrin 57b).


Forbidden sexual relations, how so? Any prohibited sexual relation that a Jewish court would inflict capital punishment, the sons of Noach are forbidden [from doing so]. And every prohibited sexual relation that a Jewish court would prohibit, the sons of Noach are put to death on their account according to Rabbi Meir. But the Sages say, there are many forbidden sexual relations on account of which a court would not inflict capital punishment and about which the sons of Noach are not warned (Tosefta Avodah Zarah 9:4).

The tosefta seems to be saying the opposite of the Talmud.  The Talmud says that sexual offenses that Jews receive non-capital punishment for are permitted to gentiles, but the tosefta says that gentiles are executed for anything that is a sexual offense for a Jew.  Also, what does it mean by “not warned”?  Does this mean it is permitted to gentiles or that they are executed for it without a warning?  That sentence in the Talmud seems to be saying there are more sexual offenses for gentiles beyond ones that are capital offenses for Jews, so why wouldn’t they be warned?

First off, the Talmud is citing the Tosefta, not the other way around. Secondly, the text of the two sources is the same in Hebrew, so the issue is translation/interpretation, not the sources themselves.

I haven't learned this area, but in principle, a Tosefta is an earlier source and therefore stronger than the Gemara. The Gemara will cite various Toseftas and Mishnahs to determine the consensus, and then rule based on that. Even if they do disagree, it would be because the Gemara is basing its ruling on another Mishnah or Tosefta which argues.

@magicker72 Talmud: אין ב"ד של ישראל ממיתין עליה אין בן נח מוזהר עליה. Tosefta: וכל ערוה שב"ד של ישראל מוזהרים עליה בני נח מומתין עליה.

When the Talmud says that it's quoting a baraita, it's most likely referring to this very Tosefta (the Tosefta is a collection of baraitot); it isn't the Tosefta misinterpreting the Talmud. Still, there is a contradiction between the sources (and not a variance in wording which wouldn't be unusual). The printed text of the Tosefta seems to be corrupt here, and needs to be emended:

The Erfurt manuscript of the Tosefta simply omits the second half of the words attributed to Rabbi Meir (delete the words "and every prohibited sexual relation that a Jewish court would prohibit, the sons of Noach are put to death on their account").

Alternatively the Tosefta could be emended to match the text cited in the Talmud, since the Talmud's citations of the Tosefta are generally more reliable than the text appearing in the Tosefta ("and every prohibited sexual relation that a Jewish court does not administer capital punishment for are not prohibited to the sons of Noach").

Or the Tosefta could be emended by adding the word "not" ("the sons of Noach are not put to death on their account"; suggested by Minchat Bikkurim; at least as I understand it, his suggestion of ממיתין is equivalent to or a mistake for מומתין). But this text is still odd for a few reasons ("not put to death" seems to imply that these sexual unions are still prohibited, which would also contradict the text in the Talmud; and ב"ד של ישראל  מוזהרים is a very strange way to refer to capital punishment and I think it's more likely a scribal error).


As for the meaning of "not warned," it simply means (and should be translated as) "not prohibited." The word used is for prohibition (אזהרה), not a formal warning voiced by witnesses (התראה) which is not part of this discussion.
